# Dealing with a NoReverse error

Tags: django, django-urls

Honestly I haven't yet mastered django urls. so i clearly have no idea how to go around this error.In ma `views.py` I have:

```
def get_category(request,id):
    categories = Category.objects.get(pk=id).prefetch_related('item')
    context={
        'categories':categories,
    }
    return render_to_response('category.html',context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In my `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^menu/(\d+)$',get_category, name="f4l_menu"),
```

and in my template,

```
<a href="{% url f4l_menu category.id %}">
```

this is returning an error,

> Reverse for 'f4l_menu' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

How can I fix this?

Comment: thanks guys but i still get same error..

Answer (score 1):

Try out the following:

urls.py

```
url(r'^menu/(?P<id>\d+)$',get_category, name="f4l_menu"),
```

template

```
{% load url from future %}

<a href="{% url "f4l_menu" id=category.id %}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing the names between the view and the context in the template. In the template you're using `category` and in the view you're assigning  `categories`. Fixing the view, it's end up like this:

View:

```
def get_category(request,id):
    category = Category.objects.get(pk=id).prefetch_related('item') # See? Here.
    context={
        'category': category,
    }
    return render_to_response('category.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template:

```
<a href="{% url f4l_menu category.id %}">
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems `category.id` is empty `'('',)'` in template, like the error message says. Debug it.